# Context Menu MenuItem Click Data Context?

Tags: c#, xaml, contextmenu

I have a collection of objects to which I have created a ScrollViewer to show.  For each Object, the data is displayed in a grid to which I have added a context menu so that when the user right clicks the grid, they can alter properties of the object.   I cannot figure out how to know which object has been right clicked.

In the code below, how would I know which "VoltageMonitor" was right clicked when it reaches the callback for MenuItem "TurnOff"?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,15">
        <ItemsControl Name="icVoltageMonitorsPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding AppMonitors.VoltageMonitors, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="0" Margin="0"  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:VoltageMonitor">
                    <Grid Height="130" Name="grdIndicator" Width="200" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="130">
                        <Grid.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Edit Format..." />
                                <MenuItem Header="Turn off" Click="MenuItem_Click" DataContext=""/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="133*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="67*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: The callback method should have that information in the `sender` parameter. You then can read `DataContext` of it. It's not MVVMish though.

Comment: How would you do this in a "MVVMish" manner?

Comment: The sender parameter only has Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString methods available.   No DataContext

Comment: You'd have to cast it before, `(FrameworkElement)sender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have defined an `ICommand` in your viewmodel, you can do it like this:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="local:VoltageMonitor">
              <Grid ..>
                  <Grid.ContextMenu>
                      <ContextMenu>
                          <MenuItem Header="Edit Format..." />
                          <MenuItem Header="Turn off" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                              Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                   {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, 
                                    Path=DataContext.TurnOffCommand}"/>
                      </ContextMenu>
                  </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I'm also partial to binding to the selected item of the items control. This way you your bound command does not need to worry about the selected item since it's managed by a different binding.